Flutter My Profile Image Is Not Vertically Aligning Top
I am trying to align my profile Image to top but it has remained in the middle. Here is my code. How do you vertically align a Widget in Flutter/Dart?

Please share some code and follow question asking guidelines around a minimum reproducible example.

where is your code ?

Add below line inside Row.
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start

